# Pentaho CDE Get param Function in "Custom Parameter" Component

Tags: parameters, pentaho, drilldown, pentaho-cde

I'm working on a dashboard with drill down function using the next code in a pie chart.

```
function sendParameter(scene){
       var url='https://172.18.0.152:8443/pentaho/Home?name=dashboard&startup-url=%2Fpentaho%2Fapi%2Frepos%2F%253ABIMBO%253Adashboard1.wcdf%2FgeneratedContent%3Fts%3D1436214662779&param1=';

   var vars = scene.vars;
   var c = vars.category.value;
   var v = vars.value.value;

   alert("category: " + c + "\nvalue: " + v);
   alert("category: " +url+c);

   window.location=url+c;
```

}

I set the Url correctly with the param, but when I want to get the parameter on the second dashboard I can´t. Im using a custom parameter component with this code:

```
param1 = Dashboards.getQueryParameter("param1");
```

but it doesn't work. Can enybody tell me the rigth way to use this function or is it another function to get the Parameter to use I will appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

In second dashboard you can create one custom Parameter.

**Name:** param1
**Javascript Code:**

```
       function f()
        {
           param1 = Dashboards.getQueryParameter("param1 ");
           return(param1);

         }
```

I think these information is useful to you.

Thank you.